# How to sum respective results from two data sources in Grafana

Tags: charts, grafana, dashboard, grafana-loki

I am trying to create a chart with 2 separate data sources (both Loki instances containing nginx access logs) that will display the breakdown of http response statuses over time.

The query I use in each data source looks like this:

```
count_over_time(
{container_name="nginx-proxy"} |~ `^[^ ]* ([\d]+\.){3}[\d]+` | regexp "([^ ]* ){5}\"[^\"]*\" (?P<http_status>[^ ]*)"
[$__interval])
```

And I use `{{http_status}}` as chart legend.

This works pretty well and I get the chart I wanted. However: because there are two data sources, I get each label twice in the chart. There are two 200s, 302s, 404s etc. Everything is displayed twice.

My question is whether there is a way to display the sum of the results from both datasources. I basically would like to display how many 200s (and other) we returned from both servers together, not from each individually.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe Transformations *Join by field* and *Add field from calculation* (last applied N times, where N = number of different statuses occurring in your logs) can help you.